# Failed to start ActiveMQ JMS Message Broker

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to run my project using jetty-debug. It was working fine yesterday, but today when I tried to running the project it threw me the included errors.

Any idea how I could resolve this? I have checked 61616 port, is not being used by anything else. Any info would be helpful, thanks

```
[java] 16:49:53.366 [main] ERROR o.a.activemq.broker.BrokerService - Failed to start ActiveMQ JMS Message Broker. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
     [java] java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:27) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.registerConnectorMBean(BrokerService.java:1546) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startTransportConnector(BrokerService.java:1958) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startAllConnectors(BrokerService.java:1911) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:471) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:56) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) [spring-beans-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) [spring-beans-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) [spring-beans-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [spring-beans-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580) [spring-beans-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) [spring-context-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) [spring-context-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.factory.AbstractSpringComponentFactory.createApplicationContext(AbstractSpringComponentFactory.java:86) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.factory.SpringActiveMqComponentFactory.init(SpringActiveMqComponentFactory.java:35) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.initFactory(ComponentManager.java:534) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.initComponent(ComponentManager.java:337) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.init(ComponentManager.java:290) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.loadIni(ComponentManager.java:254) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:220) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:200) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:217) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:200) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:217) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:200) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.OpenGammaComponentServer.run(OpenGammaComponentServer.java:169) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.OpenGammaComponentServer.run(OpenGammaComponentServer.java:132) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.OpenGammaComponentServer.main(OpenGammaComponentServer.java:70) [og-component-1.2.0-local-20130712123059.jar:na]
     [java] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:33) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer.bind(TcpTransportServer.java:139) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory.doBind(TcpTransportFactory.java:60) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.bind(TransportFactory.java:131) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.createTransportServer(TransportConnector.java:304) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.getServer(TransportConnector.java:133) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.asManagedConnector(TransportConnector.java:96) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.registerConnectorMBean(BrokerService.java:1541) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     ... 30 common frames omitted
     [java] Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
     [java]     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0]
     [java]     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96) [na:1.7.0]
     [java]     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:374) [na:1.7.0]
     [java]     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175) [na:1.7.0]
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376) [na:1.7.0]
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237) [na:1.7.0]
     [java]     at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231) [na:1.7.0]
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer.bind(TcpTransportServer.java:135) [activemq-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
     [java]     ... 36 common frames omitted
     [java] com.opengamma.OpenGammaRuntimeException: Failed to init component factory: 'activeMQ' with {factory=com.opengamma.component.factory.SpringActiveMqComponentFactory, springFile=classpath:fullstack/fullstack-example-activemq-spring.xml, propertiesFile=MANAGER.PROPERTIES}
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.initComponent(ComponentManager.java:339)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.init(ComponentManager.java:290)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.loadIni(ComponentManager.java:254)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:220)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:200)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:217)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:200)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:217)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.start(ComponentManager.java:200)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.OpenGammaComponentServer.run(OpenGammaComponentServer.java:169)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.OpenGammaComponentServer.run(OpenGammaComponentServer.java:132)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.OpenGammaComponentServer.main(OpenGammaComponentServer.java:70)
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [fullstack/fullstack-example-activemq-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.factory.AbstractSpringComponentFactory.createApplicationContext(AbstractSpringComponentFactory.java:86)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.factory.SpringActiveMqComponentFactory.init(SpringActiveMqComponentFactory.java:35)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.initFactory(ComponentManager.java:534)
     [java]     at com.opengamma.component.ComponentManager.initComponent(ComponentManager.java:337)
     [java]     ... 11 more
     [java] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:27)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.registerConnectorMBean(BrokerService.java:1546)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startTransportConnector(BrokerService.java:1958)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startAllConnectors(BrokerService.java:1911)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:471)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:56)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
     [java]     ... 24 more
     [java] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:33)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer.bind(TcpTransportServer.java:139)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory.doBind(TcpTransportFactory.java:60)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.bind(TransportFactory.java:131)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.createTransportServer(TransportConnector.java:304)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.getServer(TransportConnector.java:133)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.asManagedConnector(TransportConnector.java:96)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.registerConnectorMBean(BrokerService.java:1541)
     [java]     ... 30 more
     [java] Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
     [java]     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:96)
     [java]     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:374)
     [java]     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:175)
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
     [java]     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
     [java]     at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)
     [java]     at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer.bind(TcpTransportServer.java:135)
     [java]     ... 36 more
     [java] ======== OPENGAMMA STARTUP FAILED ========
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 49 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because something is already listing on port 61616.  Is it possible you have another instance running? Or is there something (perhaps firewall) blocking you from listening on that port?